# How to change the color of the <Switch /> component on react native paper?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-web, react-native-paper

I am using react-native-paper 3.6.0 and in their documentation, they offer to change the switch color using `props.color`. I have tried and:

- iOS: OK
- Android: The dark button is using `color.background`, the switch is black on black.
- Web: The color does not have any effect
- Read `<Switch />` [Source](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/blob/master/src/components/Switch.tsx) | [Documentation](https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/switch.html)

How can I set the color of the switch component of react-native-paper?

Comment: do you mean to set a color on android? because setting it up on web is not going to work for this react-native library.

Comment: for the web. I am not able to set the color just for the web. Why isn't that possible ?

Comment: react-native libraries are best suited for mobile applications only, and they are not meant to compile to html and css. you should be using reactjs for web based matters.

Comment: @kenmistry it looks like you have never used react-native before.  FYI, react-native has a replacement for web-based application called react-native-web, making all react-native library can work on the web except if there is native code specific. You can also use `require('react-native').PLATFORM` to detect your OS and execute platform-specific code or name your files with `.web.js`, `.native.js`, `.android.js`, `.ios.js` to import the appropriate source. `react-native-paper` render on the web without pain. It is wrong to say that we MUST use `.css` to style a reactjs components either.

Comment: Also, I am 100% sure that I can style the css by injecting the css in the page myself without using the `PaperProvider`, because this is how HTML works. But that was not what I was asking for.

Comment: i am not entirely sure how you arrive at the conjecture. but if that is the case, can you list a couple of browser websites that have been built using `react-native`, as i am really curious to find out how well it performs and happy to learn more from there.

Comment: There are plenty, join the discussion and I'll give you mine

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207734/discussion-between-dimitri-kopriwa-and-kenmistry).

Answer (score 1):

to change the colors of the react-native-paper Switch component I use the color property and the trackColor:

```
<Switch
  trackColor={{false: '#B2B2B2', true: '#7CAFFE'}}
  color='#214a8a'
  ...
/>
```